# Problems retrieving Fusion Tables data - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

I'm developing an JSP application that retrieves a lot of polygons to show on the map.

I will try explain how the application works before tell my problem.

My client needs to check on Google Maps his internal division of territories (a territory is a set of cities, it's a many-to-many association). The territory-city relationship can be changed anytime by loading a file via an application menu. Today we have 35 territories and about 10000 associations territory-city in the system.

I have the polygons with the shape of the cities in Fusion Tables, but when I try to retrieve the shapes, I get the following error:

**Code to load the polygons for one territory:**

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query:{
        select: 'geometry',
        from: {MYKEY},
        where: "NAME_CITY IN ("+listOfCities+")"
    }
});
```

**Error:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

I'm looking for a way to load these territories from a long time, I already tried to read the KML files from Java, and send the set of coordinates for each city, but the HTML page was like 300MB when done, and it just froze the browser and didn't work. So the Fusion Tables seemed to be the best approach.

I found out a few posts where people were telling to use the POST method to request the data, because of the size of the listOfCities variable(some territories have about 500 cities associated), but they never said how to do it using the Google Maps API.

How can I do that? Anybody have another approach to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just add a column containing a "territory" code, then query the table for records with the appropriate code in that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must somehow simplify the query. POST is not an option, there is no way to change the method used for the query.

But this could be a point where you can start:
*The territory-city relationship can be changed anytime by loading a file via an application menu.*

Instead of filtering the cities on your server and query cities, you may add another column to the table, where you store the "relationship", as suggested by  geocodezip.

This may be done automatically when "the file" is uploaded(and here you can use POST)

The new where-clause would be simple and short now like e.g.: **`territory=35`**

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dr. Molle, but the relationship is many-to-many, some cities are associated with more than one territory, in cases like these, you know a way to store it in Fusion Tables?

Comment: Fusion Tables support LIKE, you may store a list of territories separated by some delimiter. Another option would be to create columns for each territory

Comment: Thanks for the help Dr. Molle, I will implement this approach.

Comment: It didn't work :( when I start the procedure to update the territories columns in the city's table, I need to clean it, so I try to set the value to empty for each city... but Fusion Tables have any kind of limitation, when I reach the ROWID #32 it trhows this exception:


Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Request Quota Exceeded


It seems there's a limit of queries I can to execute. I tried to change the code by adding a delay of 500ms in the end of each update, but I got only to the ROWID #48.

Comment: the limit AFAIK is 5 queries per second. How many rows do you need to update?

Comment: around 5000 rows, and then I will update them with their new values again.

Comment: I would suggest to create a complete new table or empty the table and insert the rows. You may build the inserts needed for **all** rows beforehand and send only 1 query to insert all 5000 rows(fusionTables support batch-INSERTs, but not batch-UPDATEs) . Of course you can also create a CSV-file from the merged data and simply upload them.